# Установить Icon у MenuItem используя ViewBox, который определён в файле Styles.xaml

Tags: c#, wpf

Имеется файл стилей:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
   <Viewbox x:Key="icoTypeOperand_x16_Attribute">
      <Canvas Width="16" Height="16" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0" >
         <Canvas>
            <Path Data="M14.471,1H1.529C0.685,1,0,1.695,0,2.553v9.894C0,13.305,0.685,14,1.529,14h12.942c0.844,0,1.529,-0.695,1.529,-1.553V2.553C16,1.695,15.315,1,14.471,1zM13,11H3V9h10V11zM13,6H3V4h10V6z" Fill="Red"/>
            <Path Data="M13,6H3V4h10V6zM13,9H3v2h10V9z" Fill="White"/>
         </Canvas>
      </Canvas>
   </Viewbox>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Затем я в коде создаю `ContextMenu`, где у `MenuItem` пытаюсь установить `Icon`:

```
ContextMenu cm = new ContextMenu();
var dic = new ResourceDictionary()
{
    Source = new Uri("/LocalExpression;component/LocalExpressionsEditor/Styles.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)
};
foreach (OperandType item in _formula.OperandTypes)
{
   MenuItem menuItem = new MenuItem
   {
      Header = item.DisplayValue,
      Icon = dic["icoTypeOperand_x16_Attribute"] as Viewbox,
      CommandParameter = item,
      Command = CreateOperandCommand
   };
   cm.Items.Add(menuItem);
}
cm.Placement = System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.PlacementMode.MousePoint;
cm.IsOpen = true;
```

Когда я запускаю приложение, то svg картинка отсутствует. Если смотреть через `Snoop`, то в `ContentPresenter` лежит `ViewBox`.

В общем прошу помощи в корректном добавлении `Icon`

Comment: Возможно проблема в `Fill="White}"`, у себя воспроизвёл, всё работает, за исключением того, что фигурная скобка бросает исключение.

Comment: @dmepty Это опечатка)

Comment: Интересное поведение было, что иконка появлялась только у последнего элемента, думаю стоит посмотреть в эту сторону

Comment: @dmepty вот то, что она появляется в последнем элементе, это связано с тем, что ресурс существует в единственном экземпляре и он просто перекладывается из одного в другой элемент, на каждой итерации. Но у меня даже и этого эффекта нет(

Comment: Тогда может пойти по пути создания элемента в разметке? Сделайте `ContextMenu`, затем создайте `DataTemplate` (можно сделать класс с нужными вам свойствами и установить его в `DataType` у вашей `DataTemplate`) и задайте его свойству `ItemTemplate` элемента `ContextMenu`.

Comment: @dmepty Да, я так и решил сделать) Просто стало уже интересно, а можно ли без разметки как-то? Спасибо большее, за участие в вопросе!